# The .reverse () does not work on my array?

Tags: arrays, linux, swift, ubuntu, reverse

I am learning about the arrays right now in Swift.
While trying to reverse an array

```
var array = [1, 2, 3]
var rev = array.reversed()
print (rev)
```

I get this output

```
ReversedRandomAccessCollection<Array<int>>(_base: [1, 2, 3])
```

No idea why it does pop up instead of a reversed array.
I am working on linux (Ubuntu)

Please help me and tell what is wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: `let rev = Array(array.reversed())`

Comment: You can also say `let rev: Array = array.reversed()`, as `reversed()` has an overload for returning an `Array` instead a reversed view.

Comment: You need to use reverse and not reversed: var rev=array.reverse()

Comment: @MarieDm Wrong. `reversed` returns a copy of the reversed array, but `reverse` reverses the array itself (mutates). OP does not want to mutate the source array.

Comment: @Hamish Nice trick